# Width of fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

In most cases,when we study the width of a function and the width of the fourier transform of it,in general we find that the product of the two widths is more or less constant.This is true for slit function,gaussian function,delta function and many others.But how can it be mathematically,rigorously proved that their widths must have a more or less inverse relationship?

Comment: Some clarifications, if a function have a finite support in one domain, it has to have infinite support in the other one. So, in that regard "time bandwidth product" is always infinite (except for degenerate, augmented functions i.e. impulse function). What is typically meant by that time bandwidth product, where most of the energy of your function (signal) is located. In that regard your resolution is limited (A fixed time bandwidth product exists). If you are on a graduate level please check your Multi resolution/wavelet course and uncertainty property of Fourier transform

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733198/is-there-a-general-way-to-prove-this-fourier-transform-property?rq=1 seems like a better answer than mine